# Getting an empty response from Google mybusinessinformation api

Tags: google-my-business-api

I am able to get the list of accounts for Google mybusiness api but when I try to get the list of locations in an account through

[https://mybusinessbusinessinformation.googleapis.com/v1/accounts/{account_id}/locations?&readMask=title](https://mybusinessbusinessinformation.googleapis.com/v1/accounts/%7Baccount_id%7D/locations?&readMask=title)

I get an empty array with 200 ok status. I know there are locations under the account. I am not sure where I am going wrong.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you try via the OAuth 2.0 Playground? https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/basic-setup#make-simple-http-request

Comment: I get the same in OAuth playground too. I get {} as response.

Comment: you are setting only title for the readMask, have you tried to add more items ? for example:  &readMask=storeCode,metadata,profile,serviceArea,labels,adWordsLocationExtensions